# Exponent text shifts right while it isn’t expected (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I got the following code for a project:

https://codepen.io/Augustin123/pen/oNBgzKv

```
<div id="result1" class="divinfo">
    <p style="font-size: 35px;">Hydrogène</p>
    <p>Nombre de protons : 1</p>
    <p>Nombre de nucléons : 1</p>
    <p>Nombre de neutrons : 0</p>
    <p>Famille : Métaux alcalins</p>
    <p>Groupe : Non Métaux</p>
    <p class="elec">Électronégativité :</p>
    <p>Configuration électronique : 1s<sup>1</sup></p>
    <p class="tempfus">Température de fusion :</p>
    <p class="tempvap">Température de vaporisation :</p>
    <p>Bloc s</p>
    <p>Année de découverte : 1766</p>
</div>
<div id="result2" class="divinfo">
    <p style="font-size: 35px;">Hélium</p>
    <p>Nombre de protons : 2</p>
    <p>Nombre de nucléons : 4</p>
    <p>Nombre de neutrons : 2</p>
    <p>Famille : Gaz nobles</p>
    <p>Groupe : Non Métaux</p>
    <p class="elec">Électronégativité :</p>
    <p>Configuration électronique :</p>
    <p class="tempfus">Température de fusion :</p>
    <p class="tempvap">Température de vaporisation :</p>
    <p>Bloc s</p>
    <p>Année de découverte : 1895</p>
</div>
```

```
sup{
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}
```

It’s an interactive periodic table (Chemistry) where the logic is : you click on an element (e.g. Hydrogen) and it makes appear a div with information.

The problem is that the exponent text in information's div shifts right so much.

**To reproduce the problem:**

1. Go to the codepen (because the code is too many long to write it here).
2. Then click on «H» (Hydrogen) element’s cell of the table.
3. Scroll down and you’ll see the information's div which is surrounded by purple and inside « Configuration électronique : » (I’m originally French) and the exponent which shifts right so much.

**To see the div's code :** Scroll down the HTML code to the line 190, you'll see the whole div.

[image: Image link of the result]

Comment: Good question AugustinS. Next time make sure to add at least some code so the question is understandable even without visiting the link.

Comment: @Chic his code is very long. He already said it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution for your Problem!

I inspected the `sup` and saw this:

[image]

Change your CSS to this:

```css
sup {
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course, THANK YOU ! I used the position…left because of the superscript of the table (molar mass and A number) and I forgot to change this for the informations’ div. This is what happens when your code is SO LONG.

Comment: Hahaha I can understand your situation! Sometimes my head is also confused when you program for so long! ;D I'm also very glad that I could help you. Happy Coding! :D